# Solve $\sup_{\mu}\mathbb{E}_{X,X'\sim\mu,\text{i.i.d.}} G(|X-X'|)$

Tags: calculus, probability, measure-theory, optimization, convex-analysis

Suppose $G:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is a strongly concave and increaing function on $[0,1]$. Consider the optimization problem
$$\sup_{\text{probability measure } \mu\text{ on [0,1]}}\mathbb{E}_{X,X'\sim\mu,\text{i.i.d.}} G(|X-X'|).$$Assume $\mu^*$ is an optimal solution, prove that $\mathbb{E}_{X\sim\mu*}G(|X-c|)$ is independent of $c\in[0,1]$.

It's P17 of 2023 Alibaba Global Mathematics Competition. If the density of $\mu^*$ is lower bound by a positive constant (i.e., if $\mu^*$ is not on the ``boundary'' of the set of all measures), we can end the proof by doing a functional derivative.

Comment: Just to check - is this from the [June 17, 2023-June 18, 2023 competition](https://damo.alibaba.com/alibaba-global-mathematics-competition)?

Comment: Yes indeed.      ````

Answer (score 1):

https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.17608

In this paper the authors discussed the relation between maximizing $\mathbb{E}_{X,X'\sim\mu,\text{i.i.d.}} G(|X-X'|)$ and $\mathbb{E}_{X \sim \mu} U(|X - c|)$. However this is just for the case $G(x) = x^{\gamma}$. I'm not sure if we can obtain this necessary condition by employing variational principle directly for any strongly concave function $G$. Hope you can post a full solution with this :)

Comment: btw are you refering to Lemma 4.5 in this paper?

Comment: Suppose $\mu^*$ has density $f\geq a>0$. Let $\mathcal{F}[f]=\int G(|x-y|)f(x)f(y)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$. Then $\frac{\delta \mathcal{F}}{\delta f}(c)=\int G(|x-c|)f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ is exactly what we want to prove to be a constant.

Since $G$ is a continuous function on a compact set, $G$ is also uniformly continuous, so $\int G(|x-c|)f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ is continuous. Thus if $\int G(|x-c|)f(x)\mathrm{d}x$  is not constant, we can add a small perturbation $\delta f$ on $f$, such that $\int\delta f=0$, $\|\delta f\|_{\infty}<a/2$, but $\mathcal{F}[f+\delta f]>\mathcal{F}[f]$.

Comment: Yes... And I think the density of $\mu^*$ must be lower bounded by a constant $a>0$? Since, this is the asymptotic version of maximizing $\sum\limits_{i<j} G(r_{\pi(i)} - r_{\pi(j)})$, and we can prove that the solution to this optimization problem satisfies $1 = r^*_{\pi(1)} \ge r^*_{\pi(2)} \ge \cdots \ge r^*_{\pi(n)} = 0$ with $r^*_{\pi(i)} + r^*_{\pi(n+1-i)} = 1$.